# Sentry Go Integration, how to specify error level?

Tags: go, sentry

According to the official docs https://docs.sentry.io/clients/go/ you can log errors in Sentry from a golang project with:

```
// For Errors
raven.CapturePanic(func() {
    // do all of the scary things here
}, nil)

// For panic
if err != nil {
   raven.CaptureErrorAndWait(err, nil)
   log.Panic(err)
}
```

This works like a charm, the problem is in Sentry both functions are logged with level 'Error'. Anyone knows how can the logging level be specified for each call? In Python is very explicit, but I don't see it for Go.

Comment: [Severity](https://godoc.org/github.com/getsentry/raven-go#pkg-constants) is a field of [Packet](https://godoc.org/github.com/getsentry/raven-go#Packet). To set the severity you have to construct the packet manually and call [Capture](https://godoc.org/github.com/getsentry/raven-go#Client.Capture).

Comment: Thanks @Peter, I was hoping there was a more straightforward solution since specifying error level is quite essential for logging.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `sentry-go` SDK, the Level is set on the Scope.

Documentation:

- https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/getsentry/sentry-go?tab=doc#Scope.SetLevel
- https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/getsentry/sentry-go?tab=doc#Level

Example:

```golang
    sentry.WithScope(func(scope *sentry.Scope) {
        scope.SetLevel(sentry.LevelFatal)
        sentry.CaptureException(errors.New("example error"))
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice in the comments, and came up with this:

```
// sentryErrorCapture sends error data to Sentry asynchronously. Use for non-Fatal errors.
var sentryErrorCapture = func(err error, severity raven.Severity, tags map[string]string, interfaces ...raven.Interface) string {
    packet := newSentryPackage(err, severity, tags, interfaces...)
    eventID, _ := raven.Capture(packet, tags)
    return eventID
}


func newSentryPackage(err error, severity raven.Severity, tags map[string]string, interfaces ...raven.Interface) (packet *raven.Packet) {
    interfaces = append(interfaces,
        raven.NewException(err, raven.GetOrNewStacktrace(err, 1, 3, raven.IncludePaths())))

    packet = &raven.Packet{
        Message:    err.Error(),
        Level:      severity,
        Interfaces: interfaces,
        Extra:      getSentryExtraInfo(),
    }
    return
}
```

When I want to log an error specifying the level I call: **sentryErrorCapture(err, raven.ERROR, nil)**.